# gradlew assembleRelease command in react-native android is not generating the app-release.apk

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

I want to generate the unsigned app-release.apk without the react-packager server. 
I am running the following commands for that.

> cd react-native-project-dir
>
> react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/

After the following command I get the error in command prompt like these:

> cd android && gradlew assemblerelease
>
> app:processReleaseManifestessReleaseManifest
>
> :app:processReleaseResources
>   D:\ReactNativeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\drawable-mdpi-v4\image_background_unique_2.jpg: error: Duplicate file.
>   D:\ReactNativeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\drawable-mdpi\image_background_unique_2.jpg: Original is here. The version qualifier may be implied.
>   :app:processReleaseResources FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
>     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

And I am not able to generate the app-release.apk and not understanding why the image_background_unique_2.jpg file is getting added two times in different folders.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Did you use Create React Native Application?

Comment: I have used react-native init projectName

Comment: when I have deleted my drawable-folders I get the error like:              Unable to process incoming event 'ProgressComplete ' (ProgressCompleteEvent)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was trying to generate a signed APK following the steps from https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html to generate a signed apk.

I had the same issue. Showed `error: Duplicate file` for some of my images when I ran `./gradlew assembleRelease`. `assembleRelease` seems to cause some problems with `drawable-` folders. I deleted all the `drawable-` folders from `/android/app/src/main/res/`. Then I ran ./gradlew assembleRelease again. Finaly, it generated a signed APK at `/android/app/build/outputs/apk/`.

Comment: dude they are resource file that i need for the app, I can't  delete them?

Comment: @akaMahesh Yeah, good question. I'm wondering the same thing.

Comment: removing the files resulted in a new error. `./gradlew assembleRelease` couldn't fine other resouces.

Answer (score 23):

The issue is that the new version of react-native bundles the assets under /app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release instead of app/src/main/res

To resolve it, this is what I did

`rm -rf android/app/src/main/res/drawable-*`

Now bundle assets using this command:

`react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/`

Note the updated `--assets-dest` in the above command. Assembling the APK worked ok after that!

`react-native run-android --variant=release`

Comment: I want to kiss you but I can't, so please have my thanks! =D

Comment: Note that for me deleting `android/app/src/main/res/drawable-*` broke the build but the rest worked. If I could upvote more than once, I would.

Comment: As akaMahesh commented in the accepted answer, how am I supposed to delete my drawable directories if my assets are in there?

Comment: @Ash the drawable should be a generated directory - assets would typically be in your react native source directory and not in the android directory. Deleting drawables should be ok since assets get copied over when you run the `react-native bundle` command

Comment: I had to rename index.android.js with index.js. Thank's @IndivisionDev

Comment: it works to me too,Thanks. But there is a point that I don't know how to fix it.In my case before getting every 'apk' file I have to run this command.Is any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you bundled your app and installed it to your phone with `assembleDebug`. When you decided to go for `assembleRelease` then you should delete `drawable-` folders. They create problem somehow when you decide to produce an .apk file.

Comment: By deleting the drawable- folders I am getting the following in my terminal                                                                                         

bundle: Writing bundle output to: 
bundle: Done copying assets
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Unable to process incoming event 'ProgressComplete ' (ProgressCompleteEvent)

Comment: Could not get much from the error. When I read your question again, AFAIK you do not need ```assembleRelease``` if you want unsigned apk.

Answer (score 1):

First delete all folders that are potentially causing this error by typing:

```
rm -rf ./android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/drawable-*
```

Then change mdpi to mdpi-v4 in:

```
./node_modules/react-native/local-cli/bundle/assetPathUtils.js

function getAndroidAssetSuffix(scale) {
  switch (scale) {
    case 0.75: return 'ldpi';
    case 1: return 'mdpi-v4';
    case 1.5: return 'hdpi';
    case 2: return 'xhdpi';
    case 3: return 'xxhdpi';
    case 4: return 'xxxhdpi';
  }
}
```

Then bundle your offline includes:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/
```

Finally build the release version of your app:

```
cd ./android && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try a react native clean build ? Try resetting the cache and then bundle. Maybe it will resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this problem by deleting the duplicates of the folder in react native `/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/drawable-mdpi`

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

Add the following code to file node_modules/react-native/react.gradle :

```
doLast {
    def moveFunc = { resSuffix ->
        File originalDir = file("${resourcesDir}/drawable-${resSuffix}")
        if (originalDir.exists()) {
            File destDir = file("${resourcesDir}/drawable-${resSuffix}-v4")
            ant.move(file: originalDir, tofile: destDir)
        }
    }
    moveFunc.curry("ldpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("mdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("hdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("xhdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("xxhdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("xxxhdpi").call()
}
```

inside def currentBundleTask = tasks.create(...

found this solution here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5787

Answer (score 0):

you can do one things for debug to make react native bundle run below command

```
react-native bundle --assets-dest ./android/app/src/main/res/ --entry-file ./index.js --bundle-output ./android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --platform android --dev true
```

**For release:**

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file ./index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/
```